# How to unlock Nexus S 2.3.3 bootloader without having to wipe all device data?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, fastboot, bootloader, bootloader-lock

The usual way is to execute:

```
fastboot oem unlock
```

But this will erase all my private data.

Answer (score 2):

Unlocking the bootloader will wipe your device.

You can however [get root access without unlocking the boot loader](http://completeandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/complete-guide-to-rooting-the-nexus-s/).

If you then still want to unlock the bootloader, as you already have root access you can follow Sparx's advice and use a back up app before doing so.

Comment: I should have clarified in the question which Android version I was using. I've upgraded to 2.3.3, so your tip won't work. I changed the question to include the Android version.

Answer (score 0):

What if you backed up all your data using Titanium Backup / MyBackup Pro or some such app, then unlocked the bootloader and finally restored the data?

That would then leave you with (after some effort) an unlocked phone and your data.

Comment: the problem is that in order to backup my data, I need to root my device, and to do that, I need to unlock the bootloader. My Nexus S is with 2.3.3.

Comment: Really? I had no idea that only rooted phones' data could be backed up. NANDROID backup - yes, but backing up data using these programs on unrooted phones is an impossibility...?

Comment: IIRC, you need root for an application to be able to access `/data`. I think the non-root versions of MyBackup just create links to the Market pages for your apps, then re-install them from there. This guess is based on their description (I've never used it): "Users who have a rooted phone: You can backup apk+data as well as market links!"

Comment: Yep, eldarerathis is right.